# select first element which contain digits - 2014

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I'm trying to get the first paragraph which has year 2014, but getting all elements which have year 2014.

```
<p>first - 2014</p>
<p>a - 2014</p>
<p>a - 2014</p>
<p>a - 2013</p>
<p>a - 2013</p>

$("p").each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();
    var patt = /\d+$/;
    var res = str.match(patt);

    if (res == 2014){
      var arr = [];
      arr.push($(this));
      console.log(arr[0])
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just use a `filter()`. Note: You keep declaring a local array, pushing results onto it then throwing it away.

Comment: To find the first, you need to stop looping after you find a paragraph with "2014" in it. Use return after you log it to the console.

Comment: Could fit your needs: `$('p:contains(" 2014"):eq(0)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `filter()` as that is more useful generally. if you want the first you then just call `first()` on the results:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zxqegsuh/3/

```
var ps = $("p").filter(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();
    var patt = /\d+$/;
    var res = str.match(patt);

    return (res == 2014);
});
alert(ps.length);

// if you want the first only
ps.first().css('color', 'red');
```

Which reduces to: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zxqegsuh/4/

```
var ps = $("p").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().match(/\d+$/) == 2014;
});
```

Note: You keep declaring a local array, pushing results onto it then throwing it away. That seems a little wrong :)

Comment: it's still select three para - not first one;

Comment: @Pipa: It was already updated for that. Please refresh and re-read :)